# How does the win32com python.Interpreter work?

Tags: python, com

Ok, so I'm trying to google the win32com python package and the python.Interpreter COM server.  Unfortunately, python.Interpreter ends up as "python Interpreter" and not giving me any COM server results.

I'm trying to make a pluggable program that has a plugin to allow python code to run, and it seems like the python.Interpreter would be a good way to go.  But I haven't used it before and I'm not sure how to make objects created from it available through COM.

Any advice or pointers to documentation/examples would be appreciated.

Also, would a user need to install a python package to use the COM server, or is the interpreter built into the server dll?

Thanks
Brett

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://books.google.com/books?id=ns1WMyLVnRMC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=win32com+%22python.interpreter%22&source=bl&ots=NVpe-E8eGg&sig=imGi73WQyOmP4rJC6-jpz4stb9M&hl=en&ei=xrAYSsTHBZH0tAORqeCSDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6#PPA232,M1 for excellent docs on python.interpreter -- as for your second question, normally win32com is installed as an add-on to an existing Python install, but of course you can pick a Python distro including the win32 extensions, such as Activestate's at http://www.activestate.com/activepython/ .

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'd already read that today.  I actually thought the handling of python.Interpreter was fairly sparse, just a two liner from the command prompt.  My apologies for not being clearer, but I would like to have a C++ program that can have perl plugins provide input.  I didn't get a feel for that from that book.

Thanks for the link, any other pointers?

Comment: I think this is the right answer, I just need to read up on extending/embedding python to answer the rest of my question....